Is $A \in \mathbb{Z}_q^{m \times m}$ is a one-way function?
In lattice-based Cryptography, Ajtai [1996] demonstrated the family of one-way functions. For a uniformly chosen matrix $A \in \mathbb{Z}_q^{n \times m}$ and $x \in \{0,1\}^m$, $A \cdot x \mod q$ is a once way function. 
Assume $m=2n \log q $ and $(A,A_1)$ is chosen according to the uniform distribution over $(\mathbb{Z}_q^{n \times m}, \mathbb{Z}_q^{n \log q \times m})$. Let $A^\prime=[A|A_1] \in \mathbb{Z}_q^{m \times m}$. For any vector $x \in \{0,1\}^m$, is $A^\prime \cdot x$ a one-way function?

I don't understand how do you get $A'\in\mathbb Z^{m\times m}_q$ when $A\in\mathbb Z_q^{n\times m}, A_1\in\mathbb Z_q^{n\log q\times m}$? They do not have the same number of rows.

$A'$ is a uniformly chosen square matrix in $q$, which means it has good probability of being invertible. When that is the case, you can invert the function $x \mapsto A' x$ very easily by inverting the matrix.
See this discussion for the exact probability that a square matrix in $\mathbb{Z}_q^{m\times m}$ is invertible. Basically, the probability increases with $q$ and decreases with $m$. But for a fixed $q$, the probability is always above a limit which can be found as QPochhammer[1/q] in Wolfram Alpha. For $q=2$, the limit is approximately 0.29. Thus in any field $\mathbb{Z}_q$ (so $q$ prime), a random matrix of any size always has better than 28% chance of being invertible.

If we choose $A^\prime \in \mathbb{Z}_q^{m \times m}$ is a non-invertible square matrix?

@preethi I think the point is, every new row of $A'$ limits the possible value of $x$, if the new row is independent to the previous ones. That is, you are more possible to solve the linear system of $A'x=b$. When it comes the invertible $A'$, as mentioned by Mikero, the system has and only has one solution, and the function $A'x$ is not surjective anymore. So back to your comment, if $A'$ is not invertible, I think we need better reduction to the lattice problem or relax the parameters, and this is related the column space of $A'$.
